# How to render a text conditionally, based on a value form a list?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm using a `ListBox` to display a list in my C# user control. This is my list:

```
private ObservableCollection<AlarmInfo> _widgetData = new ObservableCollection<AlarmInfo>() {
    new AlarmInfo
    {
        AlarmType = "warning",
        AlarmLabel = "PLC Alarm 1",
        AlarmTimeStamp = new DateTime()
    },
    new AlarmInfo
    {
        AlarmType = "error",
        AlarmLabel = "Vision Error A",
        AlarmTimeStamp = new DateTime()
    },
    new AlarmInfo
    {
        AlarmType = "warning",
        AlarmLabel = "PLC Alarm 2",
        AlarmTimeStamp = new DateTime()
    },
    new AlarmInfo
    {
        AlarmType = "warning",
        AlarmLabel = "PLC Alarm 3",
        AlarmTimeStamp = new DateTime()
    },
};
```

I want to display the letter `W` if the AlarmType is `warning` and display the letter `E` if the AlarmType is `error`.

This is my XAML file. Right now it's only showing the alarm type itself.

```
<ListBox Margin="20" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=WidgetData}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <!--I want to the conditional rendering here-->
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding AlarmType}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I'm really new to this tech stack. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Use a Binding Converter or a DataTrigger. In either case AlarmType should better be an enum.

Comment: @Clemens Is it possible to do it with a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DataTriggers` to check for the values and set the `Text` accordingly.

```
<TextBlock DataContext="{Binding AlarmType}">
   <TextBlock.Style>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}">
         <Setter Property="Text" Value="{x:Static system:String.Empty}"/>
         <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="warning">
               <Setter Property="Text" Value="W"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="error">
               <Setter Property="Text" Value="E"/>
            </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
   </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

Alternatively, you can use a value converter (this one could even be two-way if needed).

```
public class AlarmTypeConverter : IValueConverter
{
   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      if (!(value is string alarmType))
         return null;

      switch (alarmType)
      {
         case "warning": return "W";
         case "error": return "E";
         default: return null;
      }
   }

   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      throw new NotImplementedException("Not needed right now.");
   }
}
```

In XAML you can create an instance of the converter and use it for the `Text` binding.

```
<DataTemplate>
   <DataTemplate.Resources>
      <local:AlarmTypeConverter x:Key="AlarmTypeConverter"/>
   </DataTemplate.Resources>
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding AlarmType, Converter={StaticResource AlarmTypeConverter}}"/>
   </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

---

As a general note on your `AlarmType` property. Consider creating string constants for each type of alarms if *you really need to use* `strings` here, so you reduce the risk of errors due to typos. Even better would be to create a dedicated `enum` that convers all alarm types.

```
public enum AlarmType
{
   Warning,
   Error
}
```